# Selecting existence of child relationship (subquery) as 1/0 column

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to get the result of a subquery as a column that is 1 or 0 based on its relationship.

This is a heavy report as well, so I want to avoid extra queries after the initial query.

```
DB::raw('EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM issues 
   WHERE time.id = issues.parent_id 
      AND parent_type = \'' . TimeRecord::class . '\' 
      AND deleted_at IS NULL
   ) AS flagged')
```

The rest of the query works, and even with this still works (just always is 0 even for rows that should be 1.

I have not found any instance of `EXISTS` used like this, but I have not found any alternative used as a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `COUNT`?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM issues 
WHERE time.id = issues.parent_id 
   AND parent_type = \'' . TimeRecord::class . '\' 
   AND deleted_at IS NULL
```

Comment: It ended up not being completely correct but took me down the right path, didn't think the output of a class does not actually escape the backslashes when using a raw query. Much more simple then trying to force `EXISTS` to work though, thank you.

Comment: That must have been a pain to find :)